# ant build script pass args to java task

Tags: java, ant

I desperately try to pass args to my java program.

I do this:

```
    <java classname="com.openedi.unece.xsd.XSDFileGenerator" fork="true">
        <arg value="-version"/>
        <arg value="${version.uppercase}"/>
        <arg value="-directoryName"/>
        <arg value="${project.dir}"/>
        <arg value="-messageType"/>
        <arg value="${messageType}"/>                       
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/EdifactConverter.jar" />
        </classpath>
    </java>
```

All the properties have default values set in the build script, but it does not work.

Thanks for suggestions

Matthias

Comment: How does it "not work"?  Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set the default values correctly. A complete ant script could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project basedir="." default="start" name="Test">
    <property name="version.uppercase" value="AAA"/>
    <property name="project.dir" value="PATH/TO/DIR"/>
    <property name="messageType" value="MESSAGETYPE"/>
    <property name="lib.dir" value="PATH/TO/LIB"/>
    <target name="start">
        <java classname="com.openedi.unece.xsd.XSDFileGenerator" fork="true">
            <arg value="-version"/>
            <arg value="${version.uppercase}"/>
            <arg value="-directoryName"/>
            <arg value="${project.dir}"/>
            <arg value="-messageType"/>
            <arg value="${messageType}"/>                       
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/EdifactConverter.jar" />
            </classpath>
        </java>
    </target>
</project>
```